# I am looking after a tool to test recursive a authenticated web application passing from all links and to find error pages and broken links

Tags: testing, automated-tests

This tool should to login in a authenticated web application and pass through entire web application links recursive and to find error pages or broken links.
I tried to implement myself a tool to do this job using Watin but doesn't work.

https://github.com/adavidoaiei/Check-Broken-Links-and-Error-Pages-in-ASP.NET/blob/master/WindowsFormsApplication1/WindowsFormsApplication1/Main.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This scenario can be easily tested by selenium, if you are familiar with Selenium tool.
You just need to download the selenium jar and use this in a project created in JAVA (can be any other language) using eclipse and then write a simple code to check all links on a web page.

Sample code can be:
Webdriver driver = new Firefoxdriver();
//Browse URL
driver.get("ENTER UR URL");

//Enter User name and Password
driver.findElement(By.id("ENTER USER ID ELEMENT DEFINITION")).sendKeys("ENTER UR USER NAME");
driver.findElement(By.id("ENTER PASSWORD ELEMENT DEFINITION")).sendKeys("ENTER UR PASSWORD");
driver.findElement(By.id("ENTER SUBMIT ELEMENT DEFINITION")).click();

//Go To Desire Screen
driver.findElement(By.id("ENTER Desire Option ELEMENT DEFINITION")).click();

List<Webelement> webelementList = new ArrayList<Webelement>;
webelementList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

for(int i=0; i<webelementList.size(); i++)
{
driver.get(webelementList.get(i));
if(driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Page"))
{
<Write Validation>
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very easily via PowerShell's [IE COM object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/09/10/controlling-internet-explorer-object-from-powershell.aspx). This is [my article](http://myqaengineering.blogspot.com/2014/08/where-is-my-automation-level.html) about such automation  (implementation of user_agent). In your case you just need first part of the

> should to login in a authentificated web application

The rest of

> pass through entire web application links recursive and to find error pages or broken links

can be done with the code snippets I've shared. Simple code:

```
//create IE object
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $true
$url = "http://myUrl.com/?Login"
$ie.Navigate($url)
$doc = $ie.Document
//find all links in page
$links = $doc.getElementsByTagName("a")
foreach($link in $links) { 
//or you can call here some function that will check
//each link and can be called recursively for each page afterwards
$.click()
}
```